# Galaxy S3 - high minimum volume through headphones

Tags: audio, headphones, headphone-jack

I recently purchased a UK Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.1.2, intending to replace my iPod as a music player. However, even with the volume slider on its lowest non-zero setting, the volume through my earphones is equivalent to about 45% on my old iPod Touch (or about 30% with all the sound enhancements/equalizer settings turned off). This is far too high for listening in an otherwise quiet room, and is physically painful with louder songs.

Whilst I know there is at least one app which gives finer control of media volume, it requires actually opening a separate app every time you want to adjust the volume. I was wondering if there was a more system-level solution to either provide finer control with the volume buttons/slider or somehow scale-down the volume in general when earphones are connected? Thanks for any help :)